# Problems with solving two coupled lorenz equation with NDsolve

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I have a system of two coupled lorenz equations and I'm to integrate it:

```
coupledlorenz = 
 NDSolve[{Subscript[x, 1]'[t] == 
    10*(Subscript[x, 1][t] - Subscript[x, 2][t]), 
   Subscript[x, 2]'[t] == 
    40 Subscript[x, 1][t] - Subscript[x, 2][t] - 
     Subscript[x, 1][t] Subscript[x, 3][t], 
   Subscript[x, 3]'[t] == 
    Subscript[x, 1][t] Subscript[x, 2][t] - (8/3) Subscript[x, 3][t], 
   Subscript[y, 1]'[t] == 
    10 (Subscript[y, 2][t] - Subscript[y, 1][t]) + 
     0.1 (Subscript[x, 1][t] - Subscript[y, 1][t]), 
   Subscript[y, 2]'[t] == 
    35 Subscript[y, 1][t] - Subscript[y, 2][t] - 
     Subscript[y, 1][t] Subscript[y, 2][t], 
   Subscript[y, 3]'[t] == 
    Subscript[y, 1][t] Subscript[y, 2][t] - (8/3) Subscript[y, 3][t], 
   Subscript[x, 1][0] == 0, Subscript[x, 2][0] == 1, 
   Subscript[x, 3][0] == 0, Subscript[y, 1][0] == 0, 
   Subscript[y, 2][0] == 1, Subscript[y, 3][0] == 0}, {Subscript[x, 
   1], Subscript[x, 2]}, {t, 0, 500}, MaxSteps -> Infinity]
```

The problem is that Mathematica (Version 10.1) is running and running and eats up a lot of memory. I presume the problem is with the MaxSteps-> Infinity option since reducing MaxSteps works. On the other hand in the documentation it is recommended to use MaxSteps->Infinity for a lorenz system.

In short, those equations are from a book where they solved this system with a fourth-order Runge-Kutta  with time step 0.03 and t=10000. So it tried it like this after browsing through some of the other threads:

```
    ClassicalRungeKuttaCoefficients[4, prec_] := 
     With[{amat = {{1/2}, {0, 1/2}, {0, 0, 1}}, 
       bvec = {1/6, 1/3, 1/3, 1/6}, cvec = {1/2, 1/2, 1}}, 
      N[{amat, bvec, cvec}, prec]]

coupledlorenz = 
 NDSolve[{Subscript[x, 1]'[t] == 
    10*(Subscript[x, 1][t] - Subscript[x, 2][t]), 
   Subscript[x, 2]'[t] == 
    40 Subscript[x, 1][t] - Subscript[x, 2][t] - 
     Subscript[x, 1][t] Subscript[x, 3][t], 
   Subscript[x, 3]'[t] == 
    Subscript[x, 1][t] Subscript[x, 2][t] - (8/3) Subscript[x, 3][t], 
   Subscript[y, 1]'[t] == 
    10 (Subscript[y, 2][t] - Subscript[y, 1][t]) + 
     1 (Subscript[x, 1][t] - Subscript[y, 1][t]), 
   Subscript[y, 2]'[t] == 
    35 Subscript[y, 1][t] - Subscript[y, 2][t] - 
     Subscript[y, 1][t] Subscript[y, 2][t], 
   Subscript[y, 3]'[t] == 
    Subscript[y, 1][t] Subscript[y, 2][t] - (8/3) Subscript[y, 3][t], 
   Subscript[x, 1][0] == 0, Subscript[x, 2][0] == 1, 
   Subscript[x, 3][0] == 0, Subscript[y, 1][0] == 0, 
   Subscript[y, 2][0] == 1, Subscript[y, 3][0] == 0}, {Subscript[x, 
   1], Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[x, 3]}, {t, 0, 500}, 
  Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4, 
    "Coefficients" -> ClassicalRungeKuttaCoefficients}, 
  StartingStepSize -> 0.03]
```

This doesn't work either and gives me the following error:

```
General::ovfl: Overflow occurred in computation. >>

General::ovfl: Overflow occurred in computation. >>

NDSolve::nlnum: The function value {-4.153140717608156*10^1316669612242674,Overflow[],<<3>>,-2.511471835313141*10^1316669612242539} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {6} at {t,Subscript[x, 1][t],Subscript[x, 2][t],Subscript[x, 3][t],Subscript[y, 1][t],Subscript[y, 2][t],Subscript[y, 3][t]} = {1.755,3.848459941679012*10^813746572320117,<<4>>,7.073363386337455*10^813746572319983}. >>
```

I just don't understand why it is not working and how I can integrate this system. It must be integrable, since the authors of the book used the same system, so I must be doing something totally wrong here.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never use `Subscript` when debugging Mathematica code, because it is difficult to read.  The code can be rewritten for clarity as,

```
coupledlorenz = NDSolve[{
   x1'[t] == 10*(x1[t] - x2[t]),
   x2'[t] == 40 x1[t] - x2[t] - x1[t] x3[t],
   x3'[t] == x1[t] x2[t] - (8/3) x3[t],
   y1'[t] == 10 (y2[t] - y1[t]) + 0.1 (x1[t] - y1[t]),
   y2'[t] == 35 y1[t] - y2[t] - y1[t] y2[t],
   y3'[t] == y1[t] y2[t] - (8/3) y3[t],
   x1[0] == 0, x2[0] == 1, x3[0] == 0, y1[0] == 0, y2[0] == 1, 
   y3[0] == 0},
  {x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3}, {t, 0, 2}];
```

which runs to completion in a minute or so.  Values at `t = 2` are

```
Flatten[{x1[2], x2[2], x3[2], y1[2], y2[2], y3[2]} /. coupledlorenz]
(* {646430., 4.76559, 38.6208, 3250.67, 34.9892, 9315.7} *)
```

Clearly, `x1` is growing rapidly.  To gain more insight, note that the `x` variables do not depend on the `y` variables, so the first three equations can be solved separately for simplicity.

```
s = NDSolve[{
   x1'[t] == 10*(x1[t] - x2[t]),
   x2'[t] == 40 x1[t] - x2[t] - x1[t] x3[t],
   x3'[t] == x1[t] x2[t] - (8/3) x3[t],
   x1[0] == 0, x2[0] == 1, x3[0] == 0},
  {x1, x2, x3}, {t, 0, 2}];
Plot[Evaluate[{x1[t], x2[t], x3[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

`x1` is growing exponentially, and examination of the equations indicates that its value is proportional to `Exp[10 t]` for large `t`.  `x2` on the other hand is gradually coverging to `0`, and `x3` to 40.  Moreover, their oscillation rates are given roughly by `x1`.  In other words, they are oscillating enormously fast as `t` increases, and for this reason the time step must decrease as `1/x1`.  Not surprisingly integrating to large `t` takes seemingly  forever.

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes it much more clearer for me. Won't use subscripts again, thanks for the hint :)! But I still don't understand how the authors of the book where i found the equations could use 10 000 time points for the integration of this system. Maybe I understood somethings wrong :(..anyway.. thanks again :)